# Castle windsor property injection

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Im a windsor noob and im having some problems getting dependency injection to work. im using a asp.net web application.

I have done the following

```
public interface IHandler{
    ...
}

public class Handler : IHandler{
    ...
}
```

then i try to register the code in global.asax application_start

```
container.Register(Component
    .For(typeof(IHandler))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(Handler))
    .Named("handler"));
```

When i want to use the Handler i create a property

```
public IHandler handler{get;set;}
```

but when i try to use it, it is null? why? am i missing someting?

Best regards

**UPDATE**

The only thing i doto register/resolve is the following:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For(typeof(IHandler))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(Handler))
    .Named("handler"));
```

and:

```
container.Resolve<IHandler>();
```

Do i need to do something else, Does it work to run this att application start?

**UPDATE 2**

Can the problem ocour because im trying to dependency inject on an ascx controll?

Comment: It's been a LOOOONG time side I did webforms.  Is there any way to control the instantiation of the ASCX control? Or any hooks to be notified once it's been instantiated, but before it's being used by the rendering engine?  You need to hook in to one of those points (instantiation or post-instantiation) so you can plug windsor in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure the component that has the IHandler property is also registered (and resolved) in Windsor.
2. You said this is for an ASP.NET application.  The default lifestyle of Windsor components is singleton.  Are you sure you want this component shared like that?  You may want a transient or per-web-request lifestyle for this component.

Comment: Hi i tried using container.Register(Component
    .For(typeof(IHandler))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(Handler))
    .Named("handler")); for registring and

Comment: No, sorry, I wasn't clear.  The component that has the IHandler dependency needs to be in Windsor.  You never want to call container.Resolve<> yourself.  You register your components and services in the container and the dependencies will be resolved automatically by Windsor when it creates your component/service.

Comment: You have to call Resolve<> once to get the top object of your object graph. You should never call it more than once though

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the name from the registration, like this:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For(typeof(IHandler))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(Handler)));
```

Alternatively, if you *must* name the component, you can use `ServiceOverrides` for the consuming class:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<SomeConsuer>()
    .ServiceOverrides(new { handler = "handler" }));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be registering several interfaces/services, then I recommend registering by convention (this is recommended in the docs).  Consider this:

```
container.Register(
            AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Assembly")
                .Where(Component.IsInNamespace("Assembly.Namespace"))
                .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient));
```

This method performs matching based on type name and interface's name.  More info [Registering Components By Convention](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx)